# Custom Document Library Search only returning folders

Tags: document-library, search-results

I have created a custom Results Source that looks at a specific Document Library within my SharePoint site and a search box/results page to allow it to be searched.

I am having an issue though, as the search results only return the folders in which a search term is found, rather than the individual files, and I can't figure out why.

I have tried setting `IsDocument:1` and using the `ListItem` class but to no avail. Has anyone got any other ideas what I can try?

The Document Library has been indexed and is available for searching.

Comment: do you have any search query rules? Did you run a inc/full crawl? Also, what does your query look like, and your result source say?

Comment: hi mike. my query within my Result Source is: searchTerms} Path:https://xyz/Team%20Documents* (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you search a file name in the Team Documents library, will it be returned?
2. Are these files crawled successfully?
3. Check if the search display template displays all files as a folder type.
4. Does default result source work fine?
5. Check query rule in CA to see if it's configured to show folders.

Comment: Hi Max. I have tried searching the file name within the document library itself and it is only showing the folder, not the files individually. I have not seen this before as I have other libraries on other SharePoint sites I manage that will return the files when a term is search within the search box on the doc library. is there a setting somewhere I need to update?